# How to relate sunlight's incidence to its E and B amplitudes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

If I understand this correctly sunlight (as any light) is an EM wave. This means it has, for most mediums, two perpendicular plane waves, an electric and a magnetic, right?
We know both are linearly polarized and the incidence on earth is x $watts/m^2$. How can we calculate the amplitude of **E** and **B**? I know

$$E_{Re}=E_{0a}e^{i(kz-wt)}$$
 $$B_{Re}=B_{0a}e^{i(kz-wt)}$$

Where $E_{0a}$ and $B_{0a}$ are the real wave amplitudes.

My 1st thought was to calculate the electric and magnetic energies using

$$U_e=e_0/2\int_{allspace}E^2dv$$
$$U_m=1/2µ_0\int_{allspace}B^2dv $$

Where $U_e$ and $U_m$ are respectively the electric and magnetic energies, but these are volumetric not surface results and they would relate the waves to the energies not to the power.
Any ideas on how to find the amplitudes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like homework (indeed I have set this question as homework).

Clues:

- what are the units of the Poynting vector and how does it relate to the E-field amplitude?
- what is the relationship between E- and B-field amplitudes for a plane wave in vacuum?
- is the light from the Sun polarised? If not, how can you represent it with plane polarised waves?